# Firebase Cloud Messaging Error Token

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, firebase

**Error**

A bad HTTP response code(404) was received when fetching the script.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE /firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
 const messaging = firebase.messaging();

            messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(function() {
                console.log('Have Permission');
                return messaging.getToken();
            })
            .then(function(token) {
                console.log(token);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('Error Occured.');
            })
```

This is my code and I already create a file name firebase-messaging-sw.js

Comment: You aren't linking to `firebase-messaging-sw.js` correctly. Post the full HTML source where you include `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

Comment: <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/firebase-messaging-sw.js"></script>
still not working :(

Comment: What does `base_url()` resolve to?